# Rspec test fails to show that model requires an email

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I'm (mostly) following a tutorial [everydayrails.com](http://everydayrails.com/2012/03/19/testing-series-rspec-models-factory-girl.html) trying to write a test that shows that my user model requires an email:

```
 17   it "requires an email" do
 18     user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: nil)
 19     expect( user ).to_not be_valid
 20   end
```

But this fails... because my user model requires an email?

```
Failures:

  1) User requires an email
     Failure/Error: user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: nil)

     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email can't be blank
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `Factory.create` runs the validations and internally factory girl uses `save!` by default so the failed validation will cause an exception to be raised.

Use `Factory.build` instead (as in the tutorial you link to) to create an unsaved object that you can test for validity

Answer (score 0):

You can try this test like this way

```
it "requires an email" do
  expect(User.new.errors_on(:email)).to include("can't be blank")
end
```

or

```
expect(Factory.build(:user, email: nil)).to_not be_valid
```

More on this Please consult [errors_on](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-14/docs/model-specs/errors-on)

Answer (score 0):

The key things I would recommend when writing tests in the future are:

- **Readable**. Tests should be *really* easy to read (and write).
- **Extensive**. Tests shouldn't break unnecessarily and should test exactly what you need it to.

The code example that you'd be looking for is:

```
context "Email address" do
  it 'does not validate if email is nil' do
    user_with_no_email = build(:user, email: nil)

    expect(user_with_no_email).to receive(:validate).with(false)
    expect(user_with_no_email).to have(1).error_on(:email)
  end
end
```